# What does this mean in the Stack Overflow survey?

Tags: discussion, developer-story, accounts, survey

I recently did the Stack Overflow developer survey. I see and think this question shouldn't be in the survey list, because it doesn't make any sense to me:

[image]

> Do you have Stack Overflow account?

Obviously, one has an Stack Overflow account who is doing a survey on the site. How can a person, who doesn't have an account, do a survey on Stack Overflow? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you just click the link. though you'd have to find it within the labyrinth of popups and banners/ads/paid links

Comment: "Obviously, one has stack overflow account who is doing a survey on the site." - no. Having an account is not a requirement to do or be presented with the survey. In fact, there are people who don't _want_ an account

Comment: @Zoe without account is possible to take survey

Comment: That is what @Zoe is saying, 5377037 ... I could, if I wanted, fill it in, then grab my phone, turn on my VPN, open private browsing (thus not signed in) and do it again, if I *really* wanted

Comment: @Larnu wow can you show me screenshots ?

Comment: The survey is open to the public. [The 2020's survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#community-how-many-participants-have-a-stack-overflow-account) claimed that 10% of the participants don't have a Stack Overflow account. Also, the survey invitation banner is not only shown on Stack Overflow, but also on other technical SE sites like [Android.SE].

Comment: No, because I doubt SE would want me to do that, @5377037 , and I have no plans to complete the survey.

Comment: You don't need screenshots. Do the survey and open the URL in Adam's answer in an incognito window after you're done (or a container tab if you're using that Firefox plugin). You don't even need a VPN, different device, or even a different browser - just a different session. Why you'd _want_ to is a completely different point, though, and one I'm not gonna bother answering

Comment: @Larnu you don't need a vpn to do it, just go icognito in chrome and you can fill it in multiple times. I filled it in twice to confirm it, but after that i didn't fill it in. There is no IP detection, so a VPN is not required.

Comment: I didn't test it, I just *assumed* that SE would likely deny multiple people using the same IP @10Rep .

Comment: @Larnu since you have enough rep, check out my [deleted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407922/12708583). It's not IP blocked so that people can fill the survey out from work and from school.

Comment: I didn't say it was a *good* assumption, @10Rep . ;)

Comment: Let's examine this logically - you're aware of two facts **A** (survey is only for users with accounts) and **B** (survey asks if you have account). They contradict. **B** comes from an authoritative source (the survey). Normally, that should prompt you to confirm **A** before declaring **B** is wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ  “wow such logical.” That doesn’t mean doubting **B** first is abnormal though. The OP got way too many downvotes for a small possible confusion, don’t you think?

Comment: @КонстантинВан doubting the one fact you don't have support about? Yes, I agree it happens a lot and thus it's a normalised reaction in society. It shouldn't be, though. It should be abnormal to cling to false facts and use them to discredit real ones. As for "way too many"  - dunno. Doesn't even seem that bad - 24 downvotes so far. Doesn't seem like an abnormal number based on other meta questions I've seen.

Answer (score 21):

Anyone can answer the survey by visiting https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start